# Which one is appropriate as the subject of a letter?

Tags: articles

Which one should I use? should I drop the "a" before long-term or not? (this is a subject of a letter)

- Subject: Letter of Motivation for **a** long-term student visa.
- Subject: Letter of Motivation for long-term student visa.

Answer (score 1):

In many contexts where brevity is desirable, you can omit the article. It can be omitted here.

Comment: So it is better if I omit the article?

Comment: You have no reason to be concerned about using the article or not using it, in this instance. It is your decision.